# ASP website cannot recognise dll declared in a c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a problem on my ASP.NET website.
I'm using a c# class file wich is linked to the webpage like this :

```
<%@ Page Title="Page d'accueil" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Aplli_Serv.aspx.cs" Inherits="Appli_Serveur._Default" %>
```

But when I execute the page I got this error :

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ManagementObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this object is used in my class "Appli_Serv.aspx.cs" and is properly declared (using sentence and assembly added)

Maybe my "CodeBehind" instruction is wrong, I'm not sure of it.

Thanks for the help :)

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class ConnexionServeur
   {
      do stuff;
   }
}
```

Comment: Post your codebehind file please.

Comment: using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class ConnexionServeur
    {
      do stuff;
    }

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure your code behind class name 'ConnexionServeur' matches your aspx CodeBehind="Aplli_Serv.aspx.cs

Comment: It's done now, the problem is still here, but I think it helped. thanks